# Does using different hardware specs for different nodes in cassandra cause problems?

Tags: cassandra

We started using Cassandra years ago with four nodes. All the nodes have same instance size, `M5.xlarge` which is `vCPU:4` and `Memory:16GB`. By time we increased disk space for each node up to 300 GB each.

If we want to add a new node/nodes with different and higher hardware specs such as `vCPU 16, memory 64GB` (1 TB disk), does it cause problem across the nodes? It may sound silly but IOPS will be different, latency may be lower, even the data may be more up-to-date in higher spec node(maybe it chokes other nodes?). Since the traffic is distributed evenly the way new node handle the I/O will be different than other nodes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will cause problems, especially if you're using consistency level that is higher than LOCAL_ONE or ONE... The latencies when reading or writing data will be different, and even if your new nodes will answer fast, they will need to answers from smaller nodes, etc.

If you're using AWS (or other cloud provider) - why not upgrade the nodes in-place? If you're using EBS, just remount them to bigger nodes, but keep the instance types the same for all nodes.

Comment: Thank you Alex. It is hosted in AWS using EBS. Is there any tutorial i can follow for replacing old node with new one(with higher spec + volume of to-be-replaced node) ? I am not sure about the process and steps or is it going to be just stop cassandra - stop instance - increase cassandra and start again ?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html